# How to add @angular/material to an old angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I installed ***@angular/material*** using  `npm i @angular/material`  but every time i start angular app using  `npm start`  it throws below error:

```
node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module
```

slice of my package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.5",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
```

I tried different versions of angular-material but still getting same error.

Comment: try to downgrade your material angular package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that via the angular-cli :

```
ng add @angular/material
```

The ng add command will install Angular Material, the Component Dev Kit (CDK), Angular Animations and ask you the following questions to determine which features to include:

- **Choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme**: You can choose from prebuilt material design themes or set up an
  extensible custom theme.
- **Set up global Angular Material typography styles**: Whether to apply the global typography styles to your application.
- **Set up browser animations for Angular Material**:
  Importing the BrowserAnimationsModule into your application enables
  Angular's animation system. Declining this will disable most of
  Angular Material's animations.

you can read more here https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started